# Change vector type using constructors?

Tags: c++, optimization, vector

I have a vector full of integers. I have a class that takes an integer as a constructor. I want to create a new vector full of such class, using the values in the first vector as a constructor for each.

I have a feeling my current approach could be optimized greatly.

```
vector<int> integers = /*something...*/;

vector<clazz> clazzes();
for(auto& n : integers)
{
    clazzes.emplace_back(clazz(n));
}
```

Comment: What's suboptimal about this approach? Can you make a conversion function between the two types?

Comment: If you are looking for feedback on working code, you would be better off posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Unrelated: `vector<clazz> clazzes();` is an accidental function declaration.

Comment: What's your criteria for optimizing it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [a constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of `std::vector` accepting a range and allowing user-defined conversion. This is what you need:

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Full program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Wrapper
{
    int value;
    Wrapper(int n) : value(n) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> integers = {0, 1};
    std::vector<Wrapper> wrapped{begin(integers), end(integers)};
    std::cout << wrapped[1].value << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73138baf3ae2ec36)

This is not particularly more optimized, but it makes less code so less bugs and less wtf/line. Which is good (TM).

Comment: It's likely faster, since this approach to copying should implicitly only allocate once. I don't know if it's guaranteed, but a good implementation should. There's also no reason a good implementation couldn't optimize this to a `memcpy`.

Comment: That's true ---^

Comment: And it works even if Wrapper's constructor is made explicit which has left me scratching my head.

Comment: @virgesmith it's because that constructor explicitly construct `T`s (`std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type`).

Answer (score 0):

What you have is reasonable (though see [YSC's answer](/a/54132500) for a better approach).  A simple improvement is to reserve the required storage, so that `emplace_back()` never needs to reallocate:

```
std::vector<clazz> clazzes;
clazzes.reserve(integers.size());  // <-- HERE
for(auto& n : integers)
{
    clazzes.emplace_back(clazz(n));
}
```